# how to redirect from dialog to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

i have a alert dialog where if the user have no alarms send the user to the alarms section, the dialog and alarm section are in the same activity but diferent fragments

my dialog is from "LifeFragment.java" and the "alarmsfragment on "alarmsfragment.java"

how can i send the user to the other fragment?

**Update**

With this i tell the activity where to begin:

```
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    pager.setCurrentItem(2);
```

I have to do something like this?:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                        HomeScreenActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("1", ViewPager);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "redirect to fragment" - you redirect to an activity. The activity presents the fragment.

Comment: i was trying with an intent but the app freezes if i send to alarmsfragment

Comment: as i understand u wanna open centairn fragment from dialog ? and yr fragment is managed via viewpager ? u use FragmentPagerAdapter  or state adapter?

Comment: yes im managed whit a viewpager

Comment: so now depends if yr activity is present (loaded or not ) or if yr host activity has loaded fragments allready or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. fire activity from dialog (if its not allready fired else add flag):**

- define new intent

> ```
> Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
> ```

- define key for extra in activity
- put extra which fragment u wanna show

> ```
> intent.putExtra(Activity.STRING_KEY, Activity.VALUE);
> ```

- fire intent

> ```
> context.startActivity(intent);
> ```

**2. when activity loads:**

- in Activity define:

> ```
> public static String STRING_KEY = "myKey";
> public static String VALUE1 = "fragment1";
> public static String VALUE2 = "fragment2";
> private String _extra;
> private int _fragmentNumber;
> ```

- in onCreate(savedInstanceState) get intent extra

> ```
> if(savedInstanceState != null) {
>      _extra = getIntent().getStringExtra(STRING_KEY); // or IntegerExtra(key)
>   }
> ```

- set viewpager [ findview, setadapter(on viewpager), set for example tablayout with viewpager  etc]

> ```
> ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
> pager.setAdapter(Adapter);
> ```

**3. change fragment via viewpager in hosted activity:**

( for example use if or switch statement on received "extra")

```
// if example:
if(_extra != null && _extra == VALUE) {
   // change here fragment
   pager.setCurrentItem(numberOfFragmentToShow)
}

// switch example:
switch(_extra){
case VALUE1:
  _fragmentNumber = 1;
 break;
case VALUE2
  _fragmentNumber = 2
  break;
default: 
 _fragmentNumber = 3;
}

pager.setCurrentItem(_fragmentNumber);
```

**instead of String** extra value you can **use Integer** value and use it directly on pager

here u got detailed example :

**[Selecting a specified page in ViewPager when starting](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/yohpapa/20130319/1363708468)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to redirect to your activity, sending some data, for example in a Bundle, and based on this data you decide which fragment your activity should show (and if the activity should call some method of the fragment.

The intents are used to start only activities or services, not fragments.

Comment: @stefano-siano but u first need start activity if its not allready started

Comment: if i send the user to HomeScreenActivity and pass the pager(viewpager) id?

Comment: it's exactly what you should do. You create the intent, and put your data (the pager id) in a Bundle object (just call one of the "putExtra()" method of the Intent object, and then in the onCreate() method of the activity you read the data (pager id) and based on that you show the fragment that you want.